# MySQL LEFT JOIN 2 queries from different databases

Tags: mysql, database, join

I have 2 separate MySQL queries, each working with a different database, from the same server.

query using database1:

```
$result1 = mysqli_query($db_connection1, "
SELECT p.id, p.identifier, u.star_total FROM pages AS p
    LEFT JOIN ( 
        SELECT page_id, AVG(rating) star_total FROM (
            SELECT page_id, rating FROM comments WHERE comments.is_approved = '1' AND comments.rating != '0' 
            UNION ALL 
            SELECT page_id, rating FROM ratings) d
            GROUP BY page_id
    ) AS u ON p.id = u.id
");
```

query using database2:

```
$result2 = mysqli_query($db_connection2, "
SELECT 
    cas.id, cas.casino,  
    t2.amount, t2.match,  
    t3.bonus_id, t3.bonus_type 
FROM (SELECT * FROM casinos $query) AS cas 
LEFT JOIN (  
        bonus AS t2
    INNER JOIN 
        bonus_type_lookup AS t3 ON t2.bonus_type = t3.bonus_id
)
ON cas.id = t2.id AND t2.bonus_type = '$bonus_typeNo'
AND (
    t2.amount = (
        SELECT 
            CASE WHEN MAX(t2.amount) > MAX(t2.match) OR (MAX(t2.match) IS NULL) THEN MAX(t2.amount) 
            ELSE MAX(t2.match) 
            END 
        FROM bonus AS t2 
        WHERE cas.id = t2.id AND t2.bonus_type = '$bonus_typeNo' 
    ) 
    OR t2.match = (
        SELECT 
            CASE WHEN MAX(t2.amount) > MAX(t2.match) 
            THEN MAX(t2.amount) 
            ELSE MAX(t2.match) 
            END 
        FROM bonus AS t2
        WHERE cas.id = t2.id AND t2.bonus_type = '$bonus_typeNo' 
    )
)
ORDER BY $order_by $order $limit
");
```

Both queries work fine by themselves. Now I want to LEFT JOIN those 2 queries. My current attempt (see below) produces this error: `mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given`, which referes to this line: `$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);`

```
$result = mysqli_query($db_connection2, "
SELECT 
    cas.id, cas.casino,  
    t2.amount, t2.match,  
    t3.bonus_id, t3.bonus_type,
    **j.identifier, j.star_total**  
FROM (SELECT * FROM database2.casinos $query) AS cas 
LEFT JOIN (
        database2.bonus AS t2
    INNER JOIN 
        database2.bonus_type_lookup AS t3 ON t2.bonus_type = t3.bonus_id
)
ON cas.id = t2.id AND t2.bonus_type = '$bonus_typeNo' 
AND (
    t2.amount = (
        SELECT 
            CASE WHEN MAX(t2.amount) > MAX(t2.match) OR (MAX(t2.match) IS NULL) THEN MAX(t2.amount) 
            ELSE MAX(t2.match) 
            END 
        FROM database2.bonus AS t2 
        WHERE cas.id = t2.id AND t2.bonus_type = '$bonus_typeNo' 
    ) 
    OR t2.match = (
        SELECT 
            CASE WHEN MAX(t2.amount) > MAX(t2.match) 
            THEN MAX(t2.amount) 
            ELSE MAX(t2.match) 
            END 
        FROM database2.bonus AS t2
        WHERE cas.id = t2.id AND t2.bonus_type = '$bonus_typeNo' 
    )
)

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        p.id, 
        p.identifier, 
        q.star_total 
    FROM database1.pages p
    LEFT JOIN ( 
        SELECT 
            t.page_id, 
            AVG(t.rating) star_total 
        FROM ( 
            SELECT 
                c.page_id AS page_id, 
                c.rating AS rating 
            FROM database1.comments c 
            WHERE c.is_approved = '1' AND c.rating != '0'
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 
                r.page_id AS page_id, 
                r.rating AS rating 
            FROM database1.ratings r
        ) t
        GROUP BY t.page_id
    ) q ON q.page_id = p.id
) **j ON cas.id = j.identifier**  

ORDER BY $order_by $order $limit
");
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

I am not sure whether the error arises from the wrong usage of LEFT JOIN or if this is a database problem, or both. "$db_connection2" uses database2. Not sure at what stage it connects to database1, and how it gets the connection details that enable it to connect to database1. I tried to use fully qualified names for each table and database, but no success.

Any help would be great. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you considered getting the specific error? `error_log(mysqli_error($db_connection2));`

Comment: @BillKarwin: I tried `echo error_log(mysqli_error($db_connection2));` and got 1. This means that $db_connection2 works, I guess. The query connectiong to database2 only shows an error once I add the LEFT JOIN with the query that uses tables from database1.

Comment: Check your http error log for the message. `error_log()` sends its output there. It returns only the boolean true when it succeeds in writing to the log. Using error_log() should be taught to every PHP developer on day one!

Comment: @BillKarwin: Thanks for pointing that out. I finally found that file. It says there: `Every derived table must have its own alias` and `mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given...` I guess that means that there is something wrong with my LEFT JOIN? Unfortunately, I still don't know how to go about this derived table and its own alias.

Comment: Great! It's worthwhile to learn how to use the error log when you're developing PHP. I always leave a terminal window open running `tail -f` on the error log.

Comment: You should also develop a habit of checking if `$result = mysqli_query(...);` returns `false`, because that indicates an error occurred. Do this check **every time** you do a query.

Comment: @BillKarwin: Thanks! I was not able to utilize `tail -f`, though, but I found out about Notepad++, which helped a lot monitoring the error log file. I was surprised to even see a few more other hidden errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got this error message:

> Every derived table must have its own alias

The error message means that using a subquery in the FROM clause requires that you give the subquery a table alias:

```
SELECT ... FROM ( ...subquery...) AS t1 ...
```

This is so you can reference columns of the subquery like `t1.column1`.

It's documented here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/derived-tables.html

> The `[AS] tbl_name` clause is mandatory because every table in a FROM clause must have a name.

Comment: I added these two lines `**j.identifier, j.star_total**`, `**j ON cas.id = j.identifier**` to the query above that starts with: `$result = mysqli_query($db_connection2, "...` to give the derived table after the LEFT JOIN its own alias. I am not sure if this is the best way to do it, but the error is gone.